# How can I set dynamically the number for useNavigation hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to write a react Breadcrumbs component which automatically sets the needed number for go back navigation in react-router-dom.

I have an array with pathnames, it's length can be 2 or more. All items are links which go back on several steps except the last one

users(goes two pages back) / name(goes on the previous page) / type(inactive)

I decided to use `useNavigation` hook in react-router-dom to go back.

```
// This is my array, for instance
const pathnames = ['users', 'name', 'type'];
```

So I need a function/method which will look like this.

```
pathTokens.map((item, index, arr) => {
 if (item !== arr[arr.length - 1]) {
   return <BreadcrumbsItem action ={() => navigate(numberOfStepsBack)} content={item}/>
 } else {
   return <BreadcrumbsItem content={item}/>
 }
});
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function, or is there more to your question?

Comment: @samuei, the problem is that I need -2 and -1 for the two first elems in this array for the ```navigate``` and common loop index (0, 1, 2 for an item in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to compute the number of back navigations to allow per breadcrumb segment.

Given:

- `const pathnames = ['users', 'name', 'type'];`
- `users` (goes two pages back, -2) / `name` (goes on the previous page, -1) / `type` (inactive, 0)

Use the equation `index + 1 - pathnames.length` to compute the number of back navigations per mapped breadcrumb segment.

| Segment | index | equation: `index + 1 - pathnames.length` | goBack |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `users` | `0` | `0 + 1 - 3` | `-2` |
| `name` | `1` | `1 + 1 - 3` | `-1` |
| `type` | `2` | `2 + 1 - 3` | `0` |

Applied to your mapping function:

```
pathTokens.map((item, index, arr) => {
  const numberOfStepsBack = index + 1 - arr.length;
  const action = () => navigate(numberOfStepsBack);
  return (
    <BreadcrumbsItem
      {...numberOfStepsBack ? { action } : {}}
      content={item}
    />
  );
});
```

Comment: God thank you man, this works. But if it's not difficult for you can you explain why do you add 1 to the ```index``` value?

Comment: @Wells The `+1` comes from applied math. The formula started as `index - (array.length - 1)`, or rather `index + -1 * (array.length - 1)`, and when you distribute the `-1` the result is `index - array.length + 1`. From here I just rearranged the terms since addition is Commutative. ‍♂️  In other words, `index + -length + 1 === index + 1 + -length`.